# Script# IDeferred vs Task

Tags: c#, script#

So I was looking through some sample code in Script#'s samples. I noticed that Script# uses jQuery's IDeferred. I was wondering what it would take to make this work with async/await. This seems like something that would really improve code readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is interesting ... but at some point down the road.

Right now script# is still based on a c# 2 syntax... and there is desire to update it, but its going to take some time before c# 5 support can come around.